# Every time i test a file, my line count is one short. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: python, count, line

```
#I set the line count to zero 

for txt in f_read:

    if txt >= 'a' and txt <= 'z':
        if txt in vowels:
            v_count = v_count + 1 
        elif txt not in vowels:
            c_count = c_count + 1
    elif txt >= 'A' and txt <= 'Z': 
        if txt in vowels:
            v_count = v_count + 1 
        elif txt not in vowels: 
            c_count = c_count + 1
 #The main issue is here. In the sample files I tested, the total line counts both came out one number short.
    
    elif txt == '\n':  
        l_count = l_count + 1 
    elif txt >= '0' and txt <= '9': 
        n_count = n_count + 1
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when comparing strings like that `txt >= 'a'` ?

Comment: How many lines is this: "I can do this.\nNot that". Two lines but one '\n'...

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one line `"abc123"` then you will never encounter a `\n` and therefore the line count will stay at 0. Same goes for `"abc\n123"`, two lines, one `\n` => `l_count = 1`.

Therefore either make sure every line, including the very last one, ends with a `\n` and / or start with `l_count = 1` as long as *anything* is in `f_read`.

Comment: I don't think your solution covers all possible intentions. As it's unknown if a file ends with a '\n' (an empty last line, not uncommon), the characters after the last '\n' should be taken into account, e.g. to be non-whitespace to count as line.